# Does Node.js ship with latest npm version?

Tags: node.js, npm

Installed latest Node.js(as of april,18) and checked npm version it showed version 5.6.~. But React native showed warning to use latest version of it. I used command line to upgrade to version 6.0 . Does node.js ship with latest version of npm?

Comment: again check version of nodejs

Comment: downloaded the latest version of 9.11.1 from https://nodejs.org/en/ and upgraded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can refer to the [node download page](https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/) to see which *npm* version is shipped with each *node* version.

At this time, both *node* 8.11.1 and 9.11.1 are shipped with *npm* 5.6.0 while the latest *npm* is 5.8.0.

Comment: This is correct. Node.js shipped with a version of npm React native warned about.

Comment: @Rifat Is your question answered ?